# xCode Sprite-Kit - Background Image in every Scene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

My `GameViewController` redirects after start to the Menu Scene, which has white collar as background in its `didMoveToView` method. After a button press there, it redirects to `GameScene`, where:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.addChild(bgImage)
    bgImage.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
```

Anyway, this image already shows up in the menu, even though it is not mentioned at all in the code for the menu scene. Furthermore, it blocks 80% of the screen, it is on top of everything, so instead of being a background, it is an image on top of everything.

In the actual `GameScene` it is also on top of my Game Action, while the 20% of the screen has the grey background (Game Action is still working though).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Probably want to say `self.insertChild(bgImage,atIndex:0)`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this gives error "Extra argument 'atIndex" in call.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your image to the background with modifying the z position, like:

```
   bgImage.zPosition = -10
```